# Is limit in indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus, limits

Quick question. I was wondering whether the following limit is simply equal to zero or it is rather indeterminate:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x$$

For more detail: I was studying the differentiability of the function $\lfloor x\rfloor\sin(\pi x)^2$ at $\frac12$. When you evaluate the function at $\frac12+h$ you get $\left\lfloor\frac12+h\right\rfloor\times1$ up in the denominator divided by $h$ as $h$ goes to zero. Since $\left\lfloor\frac12+h\right\rfloor$ should be $0$, I guess we would end up having a situation similar to the one in the picture above. But I'm not sure how to tackle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $0$, since, for each $x\ne0$, $\frac0x=0$. So, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=\lim_{x\to0}0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of an "indeterminant form" follows moreso from taking the limit of a ratio as the ratio of limits:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \stackrel{\text{becomes}}{\longrightarrow} \frac{\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x)}$$

...or, at least it does in your case. Of course, these limits are not always equal, but they are within certain conditions. If the individual limits on the right-hand side are both infinite in magnitude or both zero, then we can call that an indeterminant form. Of course, it is clear that your limit satisfies this condition.

Of course, that doesn't mean the limit cannot be evaluated. For instance, your limit evaluates to $0$, because $f(x)=0/x$ is $0$ for all $x \ne 0$. From the definition of a limit (like in terms of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ for instance), you can show that this means your limit is $0$.

The notion of a limit being indeterminant is moreso a statement that, on the face of it, the limit will be a bit harder to solve than, say, naive substitution. For instance, for ratios which have indeterminant forms, L'Hopital's rule is a common means of finding the limit despite the indeterminant form.

In short: there is a difference between a limit not existing, and the limit simply having an indeterminant form.